# Calculate the percentage change with respect to the previous year, quarter and category

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, percentage

Using ORACLE SQL, I have a query that gives me the output in the following table(posting an image). However, I need to figure out a way to get the percentage change between year, quarter and metric in an additional column.

[image: table output snippet link]

Example: `Year 2022, Q1, apple against Year 2021, Q1, apple`.

I'm relatively new to SQL so I'm not sure if I need to sort the output differently to use the function LEAD, or if there is a better way to do it in general.

My current query with my attempt at the percent change with lead (that didn't work) is like this:

`

```
SELECT s.YEAR
    , t.quarter
    , CASE WHEN fruits IN ('tangerine','lemon') THEN 'orange'
            ELSE fruits
            END metric
    , COUNT(DISTINCT s.ID) AS COUNT
 --   , ROUND((COUNT(UNIQUE s.ID) - LEAD(COUNT(UNIQUE s.ID)) OVER (ORDER BY t.quarter))/COUNT(UNIQUE s.ID)*100,2) pct_change

FROM  s
     JOIN  sc
      ON S.KEY = SC.KEY
     JOIN  c
      ON SC.KEY = C.KEY
     JOIN  t
      ON s.quarter = t.quarter
 
 WHERE S.YEAR BETWEEN '2021' AND '2022'
      AND s.quarter IN ('1','2','3')

GROUP BY S.YEAR
    , t.quarter
    ,CASE WHEN fruits IN ('tangerine','lemon') THEN 'orange'
            ELSE fruits
            END
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
With my query as (
    ...your original query as above goes here...
)
Select curr.year, curr.quarter, curr.metric
    , curr.count as current_count
    , Case When prior.count is null then prior.count else if prior.count = 0 then null else (curr.count - prior.count)/ prior.count*100 as pct_chg
From my_query curr Left Outer Join my_query prior
  On curr.year-1 = prior.year and
     curr.qtr=prior.qtr and
     curr.metric=prior.metric
```